# Navigate back with navController

Tags: android, navigation, android-jetpack-compose

I have homeScreen which is waiting for intent, after i recieve it I call ResponseInfoScreen and I want to go back from it.

Screen:

```
object ResponseInfo : Screen(route = "response_info_screen") {
        fun passResponseInfo(responseInfo: String): String {
            return "$route/$responseInfo"}
}
```

Graph:

```
composable(
            route = Screen.ResponseInfo.route + "/{$RESPONSE_ID_KEY}",
            arguments = listOf(navArgument(RESPONSE_ID_KEY) {
                type = NavType.StringType
            })
        ) { backStackEntry ->
            ResponseInfo(
                navController = navController,
                responseInfo = backStackEntry.arguments?.getString(RESPONSE_ID_KEY),
                onNavigateToHome = { navController.navigate(Screen.Home.route) }
            )}
```

HomeScreen:

```
navController.navigate(Screen.ResponseInfo.passResponseInfo(paymentResponseJSONString)){
            popUpTo(Screen.Home.route){
                inclusive = true
            }}
```

ResponseInfo:

```
 TopAppBar(
        title = { Text("BACK") },
        navigationIcon = {
            IconButton(onClick = {
                navController.popBackStack()
            }) {
                Icon(Icons.Default.ArrowBack, contentDescription = "Back")
            }
        }
    )
```

I tried with onNavigateToHome and popBackStack as u can see.